# Neither .click() nor .trigger("click") work for a mobile jquery icon button. How can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

this is the js code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   if (service=="ON"){$("#button").click();} 

  else if (service=="OFF") {$(".content").fadeTo(100, 0.4);
} 
});
```

these are the js script sources:

```
 < script src = "js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" >< /script>

< script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js">< /script>
```

this is the button :

```
< button id="button" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-power ui-btn-icon-notext">< /button>
```

Comment: instead of $(document).ready(function() {... use the jQuery Mobile pagecreate event $(document).on("pagecreate","#YourPageID", function(){ ...

Comment: the complete code is toooooooo loooooong, because i use jquery and js to read an xml file content, here is a small part of the code that contains the service variable : window.addEventListener('load',function(){
  var xml=new XMLHttpRequest() ;
  xml.open("GET", "STB_PRD.xml",false) ;
  xml.send();        var doc=xml.responseXML ;
  var root = doc.getElementsByTagName("SAP") ;                                        var params= root[0].getElementsByTagName("PARAMS");
  console.log(params) ;
 var service = params[0].getElementsByTagName("SERVICE")[0].innerHTML;    console.log(service); });

Answer (score 1):

Very basic but just to make sure...
First thing I would check is if the condition is being met. If you debug your code, is it actually trying to execute the .click()?
Second, I'm assuming there is a valid function for you click to execute e.g. $("#button").click(function () { // do something.. }

Answer (score 0):

When I used focus() and blur() instead of click() everything was ok, but i want the button to be clicked, i used trigger, bind, live, and i changed the jquery versions, but it didnt work. so the solution i found is to make the button as if it is clicked by changing its color (class) by addClass(), i know its not a real solution but nothing could work